# Intercept and forward request in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've the following config in  my application.properties -

```
server.servlet.context-path=/
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/abc
```

and I need to forward `localhost:8080/home.html` to `localhost:8080/abc/home.html`.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this could work with a configuration. I use an [interceptor for the language slug](https://github.com/alaugks/spring-messagesource-xliff-example-spring-boot/blob/cc6f6258fad1ba78873090d2190c32a9ec489c41/src/main/java/com/example/demo/interceptor/UrlLocaleInterceptor.java) that does something similar.

Here is an example with a programmatic approach:

```java
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class UrlInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws IOException {
        if (!request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/abc/")) {
            response.sendRedirect("/abc" + request.getRequestURI());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Config**

```java
import com.example.demo.interceptor.UrlLocaleInterceptor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class InterceptorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final UrlInterceptor urlInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    public InterceptorsConfig(UrlInterceptor urlInterceptor) {
        this.urlInterceptor = urlInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(this.urlInterceptor);
    }
}
```